# getHitTestResult().getType() on an iframe in a WebView always returns 0

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to override the behavior when the user taps an iframe link in a WebView (a DroidGap WebView, to be precise) in order to have that link open up in Android's browser. I believe code like this ought to be sufficient to achieve that:

```
  public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.contains("foo")) {
      if(view.getHitTestResult().getType() > 0){
        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        view.stopLoading();
      }
    }
  }
```

However, whenever I tap anywhere in the iframe, the type HitTestResult type is always 0 (i.e. unknown). Any idea why this might be?

Comment: I had similar problem but instead in WebView.onLoadResource I was trying to get WebView.getHitTestResult() when onTouch event was received. For some still unknown to me reason it's type was unknown. So I tried getting it in WebView.shouldOverrideUrlLoading method and it worked. I can't give you a reason why though. Hope it helps you too!.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion, Elena. Unfortunately, the particular event I'm trying to capture is happening in an iframe, and WebView.shouldOverrideUrlLoading isn't called for iframes.